# How to integrate with Urban airship on client side

Tags: iphone

I am working on Apple Push Notification, and i am calling urban airship API for integration. I am facing problem when i import `UAPush.h`  and `UAPushAir.h` that "No Such directory or file exist". Someone guide me another easy tut please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you follow [those steps](http://urbanairship.com/docs/richpush_client.html#setup-reference), especially setting the **Header search path** setting variable.

Comment: should i set fully qualified name or just set directory name, like i set now fully qualified name "/Volumes/mac 2/Projects Data/Live Projects/MyProject/Airship", is this right or not?

Comment: Set a path relative to your project.

Comment: tnx bro, now its working... Now i just get one error and that is "UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey" is undeclare can you also please help me on that?

Comment: @Aleem, I have the same issue. And I found in the early version, UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey does exist in UAPushAir.h. However, in latest version 2.0, it's missing. Have you found a solution on it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems either you did some mistake when import the files. Try again by adding references again. You can do one thing that copy all the files to your project folder then add them to your project and do not check the option "copy to resources folder" because you already did that.

Comment: I did this, but it is still not working. Actually i can't see UAPush and UAPushAir.h classes into Push folder which i added into project, and it also show error that no such directory or file exist, can you suggest me some better?